# Trying to make coordinates for battleship, can't figure out how to make x row - a,b,c,... and y row- 1,2,3...,10

Tags: c#, console

I want to make the x row- `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j` and y row- `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`
but I seriously can't figure out how it's done... here is the code  I currently have:

```
namespace BattleShip.UI
{
    public class Boards
    {
        public void DrawBoard()
        {
            char[,] Hi = new char[11, 11];
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
                {
                    Hi[i, j] = 'A';
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"   {Hi[0, i]}    ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("        ");
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" - - -  ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write($"   {Hi[i, 0]}    ");
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($" - {Hi[i, j]} -  ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("        ");
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" - - -  ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither the question nor the code makes sense. Try including an exact example of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You create an 11x11 array - that has 121 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a 2D array but pre define your lables for the axis. When you create a 2D array you are just going to hold values based on the index of the array.

The way you are currently doing it is going to be difficult however, using a 2D array is a good idea for a BattleShip type game since the array will always be square.

If I where you I would create the array, then in each index put a 1 or a 0 depending if a ship exists on that "square". When a user types a location like "A3" I would convert the letter (with a method) and check the array at that location. If there's a 1 its a hit! If there a 0 its a miss!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently struggling with building battleship but was able to print the boards for the two users playing.

Here is my code for adding the 1 2 3 ... and A B C D ... on the outside of the users boards.

namespace BattleShip.UI
{
    public class PrintBoard
    {
        public static void printboard(Board board)
        {

```
        Console.WriteLine("  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{LetterToWrite(i)}");
            for (int y = 1; y <= 10; y++)
            {

                Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(i, y);
                ShotHistory ValShotHist = board.CheckCoordinate(coordinate);
                switch (ValShotHist)
                {
                    case ShotHistory.Unknown:
                        Console.Write(" ! ");
                        break;
                    case ShotHistory.Miss:
                        Console.Write(" M ");
                        break;
                    case ShotHistory.Hit:
                        Console.Write(" H ");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Write(" ! ");
                        break;
                }
            }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
   }
    public static char LetterToWrite(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                return  'A';
            case 2:
                return 'B';
            case 3:
                return 'C';
            case 4:
                return 'D';
            case 5:
                return 'E';
            case 6:
                return 'F';
            case 7:
                return 'G';``
            case 8:
                return 'H';
            case 9:
                return 'I';
            default:
                return 'J';
        }

    }
}
```

}